# CKAN Docker install seems perfect except ckan container exits immediately after a restart

Tags: docker, ckan

My CKAN Docker install seems perfect except that the ckan container exits immediately after a restart.**strong text**I have repeatedly tried a rebuild of the docker containers. I see no errors except a reference to the deprecation of python2. Please advise on any issues that I may have overlooked or something missing. This installation is on Ubuntu 19.10.

docker log is as follows:

```
Command 'db' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)
Known commands:
  create       Create the file layout for a Python distribution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ckan-paster", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 806, in run
    command.load().summary))
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2321, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2327, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckanext/datapusher/cli.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ckan.lib.cli as cli
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ckan.cli import load_config as _get_config
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckan/cli/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from configparser import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named configparser
Command 'db' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)
Known commands:
  create       Create the file layout for a Python distribution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ckan-paster", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 806, in run
    command.load().summary))
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2321, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2327, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckanext/datapusher/cli.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ckan.lib.cli as cli
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ckan.cli import load_config as _get_config
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckan/cli/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from configparser import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named configparser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ckan-paster", line 8, in <module>
Command 'db' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)
Known commands:
  create       Create the file layout for a Python distribution
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 806, in run
    command.load().summary))
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2321, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2327, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckanext/datapusher/cli.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ckan.lib.cli as cli
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ckan.cli import load_config as _get_config
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckan/cli/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from configparser import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using python 2.7 but importing [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), which is Python 3 module. Check which version you are pooling from the Docker, I think you need 2.8.x tag as the latest stable.

Comment: Per instructions we did:

cd /path/to/my/projects
git clone https://github.com/ckan/ckan.git
git checkout tags/ckan-2.8.2

Then we stopped and deleted all Docker containers.
Finally we did:
docker-compose up -d --build

Both python2.7 and python3 are installed but tried same with only each one installed.

Same result.